# What is the right timer to use for waiting for long periods ( 24 hours or more)?

Tags: c#, timer, sleep, wait

What is the best way to simply wait for 24 hours +/- 1 second. I know that Threading.Sleep for a long time is not accurate and can vary based on the CPU loads.

I see the System.Timers.Timer allows you to create a timed event. How do I use this to simply wait for 24 hours?

```
private void myTest{
            // SET SOMETHING UP
            m_theTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            m_theTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OurTimerCallback);
            const int hrsToMs = 60 * 60 * 1000;
            m_theTimer.Interval = TestPeriodHours * hrsToMs;
            m_theTimer.Enabled = true;

            //---->want to wait for 24 hours<------
            // RESUME TEST HERE
            VerifySomething()

     }

public void OurTimerCallback(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Received a callback, the time is {0}", e.SignalTime);
    }
```

Comment: Just create a timer that fires each second and checks if needed interval reached.

Comment: The frustrating part is to test (and fix and retest again if neccesery (and again and again)).

Comment: If you wait for 24 hours testing could be a pain, yes, but who would do that?

Comment: @Dani as if time really was on my side.

Comment: This question starts off bad, Sleep() accuracy is most definitely *not* dependent on cpu load.  No more or less than any other timer.  They are accurate to 1/64 second, plus whatever time will be needed to page fault your code back into RAM.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe Quartz.NET is what you are looking for. http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/.

Comment: +1. Trying to solve that with in program solutions wont work and is - sorry - simplistic. 24 hours is a logn time. Server soemtimes need a reset. You need an external scheduling mechanism that writes the next runtime into a database and checks the database regularly.

Answer (score 2):

+/- 1 second?  I would use a hybrid approach.

Use task scheduler to start a program, in 23:58.  Then have that program sleep for 2 minutes or less until the exact moment arrives, then perform the work.

If you don't care about the 1 second accuracy, you could just use task scheduler alone, on the 24 hour division.

Comment: I don't need to schedule a task, but just wait for 24 hours from the program start time.

Comment: The approach would be the same nevertheless. Start a timer that checks periodically, but in pretty big TimeSpans what the time is (lets just say once per minute). If you get close to your destination time start a timer with a higher resolution (once per second or even more often). +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on win forms.

Declare a datetime variable and assign a value on form_load event.
Create a timer and fire the the event in every second.
Check the datetime variable in the timer event. if timespan is 1 hour, call your main method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a combination of [ManualResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx) along with Timer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is better if you really want to use a timer.

```
    private void myTest{
        // SET SOMETHING UP
        bool bTimer_Expired = true;
        m_theTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        m_theTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OurTimerCallback);
        const int hrsToMs = 60 * 60 * 1000;
        m_theTimer.Interval = TestPeriodHours * hrsToMs;
        m_theTimer.Enabled = true;

        //Wait for call back to set flag that the elapsed time has expired
        while(!bTimer_Expired)Sleep(1000);

        //---->want to wait for 24 hours<------
        // RESUME TEST HERE
        VerifySomething()

     public void OurTimerCallback(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
     {
     bTimer_Expired=true;
     Console.WriteLine("Received a callback, the time is {0}", e.SignalTime);
     }
```

But I'm a little fuzzy on why ManuelResetEvent doesn't do the job easier....